# pytorch .cuda() can't get the tensor to cuda

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu

I try to get my data onto gpu,but it doesn't work;

in my train.py

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
ten = torch.FloatTensor(2)
ten = ten.cuda()
print(ten)

args = config()
train_net(args, args.train_net, loss_config=net_loss_config[args.train_net])
```

when it runs ,it prints this

`tensor([0., 0.])`

the tensor is not on cuda

but in test.py

```
import torch
ten=torch.FloatTensor(2)
ten=ten.cuda()
print(ten)
```

it prints this

```
tensor([1.4013e-45, 0.0000e+00], device='cuda:0')
```

now the tensor is on cuda

Comment: run `torch.cuda.is_available()` before each script and print the result here

Answer (score 3):

The error means that the ten variable in your model is of type `torch.FloatTensor` (CPU), while the input you provide to the model is of type `torch.cuda.FloatTensor` (GPU).

The most likely scenario is that you have `nn.Parameter` or other modules such as `nn.Conv2d` defined in the `__init__()` method of your model, and additional weights or layers defined in the `forward()` method of your model.

In this case, the layers defined in the `forward()` method are not modules of the model, and they won’t be mapped to GPU when you call `cuda()`.

You also need to explicitly add the parameters to your optimizer if you want them to be updated with gradient descent.